# How do I use one hot encoding with 240 nominal variables and each with equal occurrence?

Tags: dataset, decision-trees, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding, categorical-encoding

The method I saw that's generally used to deal with large # of nominal variables is to keep the most frequent variables and introduce a new "other" category. But that's not possible with my data with equal # of tuples for each nominal variable. How do I handle this? I have 70 tuples for each of the 250 categories.

Edit: After researching more, I think I should use target encoding with prior smoothing but could someone suggest an appropriate value for the [smoothing parameter](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/targetencoder.html) in python?

Comment: is "tuples"=observations, and "nominal variable"=category inside a single feature?

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the size of your dataset: if every level (possible value of the feature) occurs frequently enough, one-hot encoding is still probably fine, especially if your model can accept sparse data structures.

If the levels are fairly rare in absolute numbers, then I agree that (some flavor of) target encoding, especially with smoothing, is a good approach. Ideally, treat the smoothing parameter as a hyperparameter of the modeling pipeline to tune. The default is currently 1, but [will be increased](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/category_encoders/issues/327#issuecomment-1141399831) to 10 in a near-future version.